# Understanding the concept behind finding the duplicates in an array

Tags: algorithm, pseudocode

I found a method to find the duplicates in an array of n elements ranging from 0 to n-1.

```
Traverse the array. Do following for every index i of A[].
{
    check for sign of A[abs(A[i])] ;
    if positive then        
      make it negative by   A[abs(A[i])] = -A[abs(A[i])];
    else  // i.e., A[abs(A[i])] is negative
      this element (ith element of list) is a repetition
}
```

This method works fine. But I fail to understand how. Can someone explain it?

I am basically looking for a proof or a simpler understanding of this algorithm!

Comment: Try manually doing this on say a size 3 array and increase the size.

Comment: @Mark : I have tried and it works fine. I was just looking for a simpler explanation/proof for a clear understanding!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're basically cheating by using the sign bits of each array element as an array of one-bit flags indicating the presence or absence of an element. This might or might not be faster than simply using a separate bit-set array, but it certainly makes use of the special case that you are using a signed representation (int) of unsigned values, therefore you have an extra unused bit to play with on each.  This would not work if your values were signed, for example.

Answer (score 3):

The algorithm stores additional information in the sign of each number in the array.

The sign in `A[i]` stores whether `i` occured previously during the processing: if it's negative, it occured once.

Note: "elements ranging from 0 to n-1." - Oh well, you cannot store the sign in `0`, so this isn't a correct algorithm for the task.

Comment: You could, however, interpret `-(INT_MAX+1)` as `-0`, but that would require some special handling, and probably better to just use a separate bitset anyway.

Answer (score 0):

See http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-the-two-repeating-elements-in-a-given-array/
Method 5.

The examples there might help you.